# Help with Chromium Extension

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, extension

In Opera I use some scripts to change the style of webpages to improve readability after they have loaded.

How can I implement these scripts in Chromium using an extension, or can I make a extension which will do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use greasemonkey script extension in chrome.

For more information & usage  [www.howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/)

One more similar add-on to that [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)